# NetSuite Email Template Subsidiary Logo Script Error

Tags: javascript, html, netsuite, suitescript

I used this code to source the logo of the subsidiaries when creating email template. Some subsidiaries don't have logos.

```
<#if subsidiary.logo??length != 0>
<img src="${subsidiary.logo@url}" style="float: left; margin: 7px"/>
<#else>
<#if companyInformation.logoUrl?length != 0>
    <img src="${companyInformation.logoUrl}" style="float: left; margin: 7px" />
</#if>
</#if>
```

However, I get this error message.

[image: 1]

How can this error be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The double question mark (`??`) in `<#if subsidiary.logo??length != 0>` is testing for the existence of `subsidiary.logo`.  After that, `length` has no meaning. To test for the `subsidiary.logo.length` you should change it to a single question mark - `<#if subsidiary.logo?length != 0>`